# Deploy service to Kubernetes via Go

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

I am trying to write a Go script which will deploy given deployment to K8S cluster. Ideally, I would like the script to do something like this bash:

```
KUBECONFIG="/kubeconfig" kubectl rollout restart --namespace $k8s_namespace "deployment/${service_name}"
```

I have been looking into the Kubernetes implementation in [GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes) and the [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) code but so far the only Go APIs I found is how to create deployments like stated [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/create-update-delete-deployment/main.go#L66) But instead I want to be able to reference an existing deployment in given k8s namespace and do `rollout restart`.

Comment: You can get more example for upgrade here (https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/create-update-delete-deployment/main.go) and refer the k8s deployment's API for more operations here(https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#deployment-v1-apps).

Comment: Is there any update? Did the reply above help?